# WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat//1/' failed:

Tags: python, html, django-channels

Im having trouble getting this chat app to work. I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eGKDuJ-E1w

Here is the code im having trouble with.

I think the problem is that the roomName variable is not being used in the URL, since i dont see it between the /chat//1/.
'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat//1/' failed:

chat screen html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:500px;width:100%;overflow-y:scroll" id="div_data">

</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" style="padding:10px;width:100%">
    <input type="button" value="Send Message" id="send_message" style="background:dodgerblue;color:#fff;padding:10px;border:0px;width:100%">
    <script>
        var roomName='{{ room_name }}';
        var personname='{{ person_name }}';
        var chatSocket=new WebSocket('ws://'+window.location.host+'/ws/chat/'+roomName+'/'+personname+'/');
        chatSocket.onmessage=function(e){
            var data=JSON.parse(e.data)
            var message=data['message']
            var div=document.querySelector("#div_data");
            div.innerHTML+='<br><div style="padding:10px;color:#fff;background:dodgerblue;">'+message+'</div>';
            console.log(e)
        }
        chatSocket.onclose=function(e){
            var data=JSON.parse(e.data)
            var message=data['message']
            var div=document.querySelector("#div_data");
            div.innerHTML+='<br><div style="padding:10px;color:#fff;background:dodgerblue;">'+message+'</div>';
        }

        document.querySelector("#send_message").onclick=function(e){
            var message=document.querySelector("#message").value;
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({'message':message}))
            document.querySelector("#message").value=''
        }

    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[html error #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T68T5.png)

[html error #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvt7H.png)

some more code that may be related to the error

chat home html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chat Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="room_name" id="room_name" placeholder="Room Name"><br>
<input type="text" name="person_name" id="person_name" placeholder="Your Name"><br>
<input type="button" name="button" value="Click to Start Chat" id="submit">
<script>
    document.querySelector("#submit").onclick=function(e){
        var roomname=document.querySelector("#room_name").value;
        var personname=document.querySelector("#person_name").value;
        window.location.pathname='/sendemail/room/'+roomname+'/'+personname;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

routing.py proyect

```
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import os
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
import sendemail.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Proyecto_final.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack((
            URLRouter(
                sendemail.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
            )
        ))
    )
})
```

routing.py app

```
from sendemail import Consumer
from django.urls import re_path
websocket_urlpatterns=[
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/(?P<person_name>\w+)/$',Consumer.Consumer)
]
```

Consumer.py

```
import json
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

class Consumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.person_name=self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['person_name']
        self.room_name=self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name='chat_%s' % self.room_name
        
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                "type":"chat_message",
                "message":self.person_name+" Joined chat"
            }
        )
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                "type":"chat_message",
                "message":self.person_name+" Left Chat"
            }
        )
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        text_data_json=json.loads(text_data)
        message=text_data_json['message']

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type':'chat_message',
                'message':self.person_name+" : "+message
            }
        )

    def chat_message(self,event):
        message=event['message']

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message':message
        }))
```

Answer (score -1):

So, after searching i realized i had an small error

roomname had an : instead of a _

```
def ShowChatPage(request, room_name, person_name):
    return render(request, 'sendemail/chatRoom.html', {'room:name':room_name, 'person_name':person_name})
```

i also added `as_asgi()` in routing.py after Consumer.Consumer

```
from sendemail import Consumer
from django.urls import re_path
websocket_urlpatterns=[
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/(?P<person_name>\w+)/$',Consumer.Consumer.as_asgi())
]
```